# Managed package development on another org. How?

Tags: apex, deployment, permissions, permission-sets

I have to work on a pretty large managed package which includes among others 2 apps. I can't work on the org on which the managed package and all the code resides.
I have taken everything from there and deployed most of it on a new org with Eclipse.  I deployed all the Apex and VisualForce stuff but some things like 'custom permissions' and Apps and other things I couldn't. I replicated manually the custom permissions and I created the apps but when I try to use the app it gives me "Insufficient access to update object" amog others. But If I can get past this I think I'll be ok. I created Permission sets, I modified almost all field accesibility for sys admin (I'm on a sys admin account).
I need to be able to make the apps work on this org so I can see my code changes in action.
To me this kind of development is not very efficient. Maybe I'm missing something? We use Git but I cannot sync the main org with the changes and risk breaking something. I must first test this in another org.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you thought about create a Sandbox of the main org? This will replicate the org and permissions. See [Sandbox overview](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=create_test_instance.htm&language=en_US), and [Create/Refresh a Sandbox](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=data_sandbox_create.htm&language=en_US).

You can then use GIT or Changesets to deploy your changes from your Sandbox to your Live org.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to create a Change Set in the origin ORG including everything that you want to move and the user profile of the user that created the content and export all to the new ORG?

Maybe then you could continue working with the imported user in the new ORG.

I hope it help you, regards.
David Lirio

Comment: Never tried with Change Set because I wanted to take all the classes/metadata and I read that the best way for this was with Eclipse/Ant. Keep in mind that the origin ORG has namespace enabled. With Eclipse I managed to remove it from the classes/triggers.

Comment: Changset will only work if the orgs are connected (Developer sand box created from the package org)